# why cant i create a new user in a mixed authentication project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a user for a mixed authentication project. I am using **MixedAuthExtension.cs**. 
I encounter a problem when I reach this line
 `IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);`
but the system user is created and the **AspNetUser**.

Thanks in advance for your help

The current code creates both the system user and ASP.NET user but it fails to sync identity

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateSystemUser(RegisterViewModel model, string key)
{
    var _context = new RequestToFillDbContext();

    #region Initialise

    Initialise(_context);
    var password = SecurityHelper.GeneratePassword();
    UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context);
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
    UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
    model.Password = password;
    model.ConfirmPassword = password;
    ModelState.Clear();

    #endregion
    string serviveNumber = model.ServiceNumber;

    if (!_context.SystemUsers.Any(s => s.EmailAddress == model.EmailAddress)
        && !_context.SystemUsers.Any(s => s.UserName == model.UserName))
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var emp = new RequestToFillApplicationHelper().GetEmployeeByServiceNumber(serviveNumber);
            model.Designation = emp.Designation;
            //TODO: Query Db for Id

            //var identityManager = new IdentityManager();
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.EmailAddress,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                SystemUser = new SystemUser()
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    UserName = model.UserName,
                    CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                    Designation = model.Designation,
                    EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress,
                    IsTemporaryPassword = true,
                    //TempPasswordExpiryDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                    SystemUserTypeId = model.SystemUserTypeId,
                    ServiceNumber = model.ServiceNumber,
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    IsLocked = false,
                    CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    IsPasswordReset = false
                }
            };

            //db.SaveChanges();

            try
            {
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);

                //Assign user to role
```

I get a

> "Property set method not found."Line 258

which is below

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);
```

Comment: In that line you are not setting any property. Can you double check? sometime cleaning the solution and recompiling does get rid of cached assemblies.

Comment: I have tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding. I even declared the identity results above the "try"  and assigned the result to = " await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);" but i still get the same error

Comment: @Innocent - can you show us your entity framework POCO objects? The message feels like CreateAsync is trying to update something to the database but for whatever reason the property doesn't have a set. Like maybe ApplicationUser is overriding an existing property inside IdentityUser or something?